# Changing the Width of an <h2> tag within <div>

Tags: html, css

I have this text field and I want to reduce the width of it. However, when I try to do that, it isn't working. How can I fix it. This is my code currently:

```css
.item {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #B19470;
  padding: 13px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;
}

.index-third-box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 100px);
  row-gap: 3em;
  column-gap: 8em;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.index-third {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10em;
}

.index-third-text {
  background-color: red;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;
}

.index-third-text h2 {
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="index-third">
  <div class="index-third-box">
    <div class="item item-1" style="background-color: #805c24; color: white;">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
      <p>Search</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-2">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-check-to-slot"></i>
      <p>Consult</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-3">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-comment"></i>
      <p>Chat</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-4">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-list"></i>
      <p>Diagnose</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="index-third-text">
    <h2>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, when I change that width quantity of the `.index-third-text h2, the width doesn't change. How can I fix this?

Comment: The width of the `<h2>` is exactly what you set it to be, `10px`.  The text within that element is simply overflowing.  How to "fix this" depends on what you're trying to achieve.  Which is what, specifically?

Comment: I want to make the text fit in that red background, but it's overflowing. And when I try to change the width of it so that it can fit in there, that isn't working.

Comment: And how exactly do you expect that entire "word" to fit in 10 pixels of width?  Please clarify what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I just tried 10px as a test to see if the width was actually changing. However, it wasn't

Comment: The width *is* changing.  But the text is *overflowing* the element.  Do you understand why the word "texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext" is more than 10 pixels wide?  Maybe you want to set the `font-size` to `0.9px` too?  Something else?  We don't know.  Please clarify the goal here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is rather unrealistic, it contains only one *extremely long word* which by default won't be divided, in a container that's only 10px wide. That long word will overflow the container and (in particular situations like in your example) even the margin of the page/viewport.

If you *do*  want to divide/break it anyway, add `word-break: break-all;` to the CSS rule for that `h2`:

```css
.item {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #B19470;
  padding: 13px;
  width: 160px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;
}

.index-third-box {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 100px);
  row-gap: 3em;
  column-gap: 8em;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.index-third {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10em;
}

.index-third-text {
  background-color: red;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;
}

.index-third-text h2 {
  width: 10px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="index-third">
  <div class="index-third-box">
    <div class="item item-1" style="background-color: #805c24; color: white;">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
      <p>Search</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-2">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-check-to-slot"></i>
      <p>Consult</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-3">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-comment"></i>
      <p>Chat</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item item-4">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-list"></i>
      <p>Diagnose</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="index-third-text">
    <h2>texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, please note: If you use a *realistic* example text (i.e. with shorter words), all words will be moved to new lines if (like in your example, and without adding `word-break: break-all;`) the container is only 10px wide  – just try it.

Comment: Here, it's just one character per line. I want the text to fit in the specified red background without overflowing.

Comment: You set it to 10px width, so there is only space for one character per line...

Comment: I just tried 10px as a test to check if the width of the text was changing or not.

Comment: Well, if you use a real text (with shorter words), it *will*  change, just try it.